# Go Google app engine - can't find template files

Tags: google-app-engine, go, go-gin

I using Gin framework.
At local development mode: goapp serve
all works fine.

```
func init() {
    route := gin.Default()
    route.LoadHTMLGlob("../*/views/**/*.html")
    ...
}
```

But after deploy:

> panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: `../*/views/**/*.html`

OK. I try:

```
func init() {
    route := gin.Default()
    dir, _ := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    route.LoadHTMLGlob(dir + "/../*/views/**/*.html")
    ...
}
```

Same result.

I try fetch dir:

```
...
dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
if err != nil {
    ...
}
c.String(http.StatusOK, "Dir: ", dir)

c.String(http.StatusOK, "\nOK")
res, err := filepath.Glob(dir + "/*")
c.String(http.StatusOK, fmt.Sprintf("%v | %v\n\n", res, err))

c.String(http.StatusOK, "Dirs:")
res, err = filepath.Glob(dir + "/**/*")
c.String(http.StatusOK, fmt.Sprintf("%v | %v", res, err))
...
```

Result:

> Dir: %!(EXTRA string=/base/data/home/apps/tmp-LEIYJC/_ah)
>   OK[/base/data/home/apps/tmp-LEIYJC/_ah/exe] |
>
> Dirs:[] |

Ooops. What I done wrong?

UPD:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: ../static/images

- url: /css
  static_dir: ../static/css

- url: /js
  static_dir: ../static/js

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: ../static/fonts

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

I put app.yaml to subdirectory, cause without that another problem:
[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/dNhqV6PBqVc

**Folder structure**:

```
app/
    app.go
    app.yaml
static/
    ...
frontend/
controllers/
    UserController.go
    ...
models/
    UserModel.go
    ...
views/
        home/
            *.html
        user/
            *.html
        anotherfolder/
            *.html
backend/
controllers/
    MainController.go
    ...
models/
    SomeModel.go
    ...
views/
        main/
            *.html
        anotherfolder/
            *.html
...
```

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml as well?

Comment: @Sean I added app.yaml and some folder structure

Answer (score 2):

I found next solution.

I reorginize structure:

```
app/
    static/
        ...
    frontend/
        views/
           home/
               *.html
           user/
               *.html
           anotherfolder/
               *.html
    backend/
        views/
            main/
                *.html
            anotherfolder/
                *.html
    app.go
    app.yaml

frontend/
    controllers/
        UserController.go
        ...
    models/
        UserModel.go
        ...
backend/
    controllers/
        MainController.go
    ...
    models/
        SomeModel.go
    ...
...
```

Change:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: static/fonts

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

It's really strange ecision GAE. I can't put app.yaml to root directory for application because I got panic message for duplication import. And I can't put templates to root directory because that not under scope, only at directory parent to app.yaml

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken all of your directories should live within the root directory where your app.yaml exists.  So you would want something like this.  Also, when you want your application to access a static file directory you need to add `application_readable: true` to that directories definition.  See the next example down.  Hope this helps.

```
app/
    app.go
    app.yaml
    static/
        ...
    frontend/views/
        home/
        *.html
    anotherfolder/
        *.html
```

Example Directory Definition:

```
- url: /s
  static_dir: s/
  application_readable: true
```

Comment: Thanks for response! But app/ as sub directiry 
not an accident. There are another problem:
(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/dNhqV6PBqVc)

for example:
(https://github.com/andrascsibi/how-many-pullups)

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue than sean